# Add css class to leaflet layer during runtime

Tags: css, typescript, leaflet

I'm using leaflet to draw layers of circles (so there are several layers, each consisting of several circles) on a map.

I've saved all the layers on a featuregroup:

```
this.globalLayer = L.featureGroup();
```

I'm adding new circles to it by creating a new featuregroup of the circles, and adding the featuregroup to the globalLayer:

```
let circleLayer: L.featureGroup();

let point1 = L.circle([pos_lat, pos_long], {color: color, opacity: 1, 
radius: radius});
let point2 = L.circle([pos_lat, pos_long], {color: color, opacity: 1, 
radius: radius});
circleLayer.addLayer(point1);
circleLayer.addLayer(point2);
// etc.

this.globalLayer.addLayer(circleLayer);
```

Now I want to add a css class to some of the layers:

```
for (let cssLayer of cssLayers) { // cssLayers is a L.featureGroup[]
    this.globalLayer.removeLayer(cssLayer);
    cssLayer.setStyle({className: 'animate'});
    this.globalLayer.addLayer(cssLayer);
}
```

This works, but since the layers contain a lot of circles, this takes a while to compute. Is there a way to just add a css Class without removing and adding them again?

I've tried

```
this.globalLayer.eachLayer(layer => {
    layer.setStyle({className: 'animate'})
});
```

But `setStyle()` does not exist on type `L.Layer`

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axwL44tm/) with my current, workaround solution

Comment: This is a very interesting question. I am lazy to create a program for it, so I kindly ask you to create a Fiddle so I can play around your exact problem. Basically we need to be able to determine what is/are the tag(s) affected by the class name. For instance, an easy solution would be to define a class anyway for your layer(s), for instance myLayer5 and then whenever you need to do something related to it you can document.getElementsByClassName("myLayer5") and then you can iterate through them and add/remove classes, but keep myLayer5 for future usages.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i created a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/axwL44tm/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add a class to the corresponding layer before you add it to other labels, like

```
circleLayer1.setStyle({className: 'myListener'});
```

and then you can find this class anytime you want:

```
$('#blink').click(function() {
    $(".myListener").addClass("blink");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axwL44tm/1/).

Comment: This is what i ended up doing

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best practice but I found that you can use the layer's _path attribute:

```js
this.globalLayer.eachLayer(layer => {
    layer._path.classList.add('animate')
});
```